# How to remove .modal-backdrop class from $ionicModal?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to remove the .modal-backdrop class from my ionicModal but as the class is automatically added, I am unable to remove it.
I don't want to permanently remove the class. But want to remove it and then add later on.
I tried this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('div')).removeClass("modal-backdrop");
```

but it is not working.

Can you plz suggest how to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why you're trying to remove? Be on mind that disabling the backdrop, the user can do anything out of your modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to hide the backdrop is changing the opacity of the backdrop modal when this is active! For that, put the following CSS Styles:

```
.active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```